# Where does the system.out.println output go in Oracle Java class?

Tags: java, oracle, loadjava

I have loaded a Java class into Oracle using the loadjava utility.

This class has some *system.out.println* messages.

When I execute a method from this class I want to see the the sysout messages.

Where can I find these messages?

Answer (score 7):

*System.out* and *System.err* writes to the current trace files.

You can enable output to SQL*Plus or similar with

> set serveroutput on size 10000
>
> exec dbms_java.set_output(10000)

See the [Java Developer's Guide](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=5&frame=#advanced_application_development_concepts) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/chseven.htm#JJDEV13285).

That said, you should ask yourself, *what do I want to log, that my client would not like to see returned in the interface to my procedure?*. The answer to that is usually nothing.

I have been able to set up http://www.slf4j.org/ with a [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) database appender (I am unsure of the specifics).

Comment: shouldn't your last statement be reversed? Log4jdbc is used to log via slf4j database activity to your local log files. You can use slf4j + logback for [logging to a database table](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender)

Comment: yes, I am unsure of the specifics , it might have been log4j when I think about it.

Answer (score 7):

[An Oracle article](http://www.oracleutilities.com/OSUtil/loadjava.html) provides some useful information.

Quote:

Your class:

```
public class SimpleJava {
   public void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Here we are");
    }
}
```

Now, compile and load your class:

```
C:\oracle9i\bin>javac SimpleJava.java
C:\oracle9i\bin>loadjava -user scott/tiger SimpleJava.class
```

From SQL*Plus, create the PL/SQL wrapper to invoke the newly loaded Java class:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure call_simplejava
  2  as language java
  3  name 'SimpleJava.showMessage()';
  4  /
```

Execute the code from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> call dbms_java.set_output(50);
```

Call completed.

```
SQL> execute call_simplejava;
Here we are
```

Comment: The url does not work anymore link form the archive -https://web.archive.org/web/20070830154541/http://www.oracleutilities.com/OSUtil/loadjava.html