# How to see System.out.println from within Java compiled in the Orcale DB using TOAD?

Tags: java, oracle, toad

The entire process is working almost properly but I'd like to add some debug for a specific issue.

```
for (int j = 0; j < end.length; j++) {
    String remove = end[j].trim();
    if (cName.endsWith(remove)) {
        mPhone = cName.substring(0, cName.length() - remove.length()).trim();
    }
    System.out.println(cName + ", " + remove + ", " + mPhone);
}
```

Where should I expect to see the output? It is not in the Script Output tab, or the DBMS Output tab, or the General tab.

Comment: See if this link helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267545/where-does-system-out-println-output-goes-in-oracle-java-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been some time since I've looked into it my self but as per [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267545/where-does-system-out-println-output-goes-in-oracle-java-class), you may need to execute

```
set serveroutput on size 10000
exec dbms_java.set_output(10000)
```

and then try executing.